# How can i order by descending on a field after casting it to integer field

Tags: django-queryset

I want to filter some events and order them by a field event_rating where event_rating is actually an integer field stored as string. I am casting event_rating to integer and trying to order by event_rating in a descending order. But it gives me the error shared below my code. How can I achieve casting and ordering descending on a column?

```
Events.objects.filter(start_time__lte=some_start_time)\
                .exclude(event_id__in=excluded_event_ids)\
                .order_by('-start_time', Cast('-event_rating', IntegerField()))
```

It gives me error like -

```
Cannot resolve keyword '-event_rating' into field.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`.desc(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.Expression.desc) to order in descending order:

```
Events.objects.filter(
    start_time__lte=some_start_time
).exclude(
    event_id__in=excluded_event_ids
).order_by('-start_time', Cast('event_rating', IntegerField()).desc())
```

I would however advise to turn `event_rating` into an `IntegerField` itself, this will be more efficient, and makes it impossible to store for example `'foo'` in the database.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Event` instead of <s>`Events`</s>.

Comment: A work around for this is like 
`Events.objects.filter(
    start_time__lte=some_start_time
).exclude(
    event_id__in=excluded_event_ids
).annotate(int_rating=Cast('event_rating', IntegerField())).order_by('-start_time', '-int_rating').values( *[f.name for f in Events._meta.get_fields()])`
the last `values(*columns)` I just had to do to ignore the int_rating
But the above soln works for Django Version: 3.2.13